# Getting alt text of featured image

Tags: images, tags, media

I'm trying to get the alt text of our featured image and have it output on the frontend.

Currently my code is

```
<img class="vehicle-photo" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" alt="<?php the_post_thumbnail_caption();?>" />
```

But on the frontend, it is outputting as

```
<img class="vehicle-photo" src="photo url here" alt="">
```

Answer (score 14):

The alt text is stored as post meta on the attachment, and can be retrieved with `get_post_meta()` combined with `get_post_thumbnail_id()`:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ); ?>
```

But if you just use the [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) function then you don't need to bother, the img tag will be output for you, with the alt text:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'vehicle-photo'] ); ?>
```

Comment: the_post_thumbnail() also allows you to select a proper rendered size for the image, so the image is not unnecessarily large.

Answer (score 1):

Please try code given below:

```
<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
$alt_text = get_post_meta($image_id , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);?>//Variable name updated

<img class="vehicle-photo" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text ;?>" />
```